Using only a portion of a screen for Windows 11
So, I usually use a 72-inch 4k TV as a monitor. Recently a portion of it was damaged and has about a half-inch line running the length of the screen vertically. This is over on one edge of the monitor but is always in the way. My question is, how do I/can I, set the Windows 11 desktop to only display on the undamaged portion of the screen?
Basically, I'm asking if the desktop can be resized the same way that you would any tab or app.

The display itself would have to support this, many larger monitors are comprised of multiple displays, instead of a single display. Most TV displays are a singular display.

Use DisplayFusion as explained in this answer to create two virtual monitors on the same screen. Then, use just one of these monitors

If the damaged area is along the borders of the screen,
you could use the donationware
DesktopCoral :

DesktopCoral is an unusual program designed to "reserve" some portion
of your desktop which is shielded from maximized applications..
Essentially, it acts like an invisible resizeable docking bar, which
can be docked to any side of your desktop. This invisible dock acts as
a barrier to maximized applications and essentially shields this area
of your desktop from other applications.
Within this shielded area you might put certain application windows
that you want to be always visible, or you might put one of the many
desktop tools like a calendar or system information component.

The app creates a floating window that you need to drag to the
damaged area.
As you might not be able to interact with that part of your screen,
you might need to start it with command parameters.
According to the Help file of the application (DesktopCoral.chm),
the call might look like the following in order to reserve the
top 200 pixels of the screen:
DesktopCoral.exe -placement top -dockheight 200

To dismiss the app, right-click its area and select "Exit"
(or kill it from the Task Manager).
